# Output parsed JSON to template in lift

Tags: json, lift

Using Lift's json parser, how can I output parsed json objects into a template?

The datatypes that **net.liftweb.json.JsonParser** provides are not
standard lists.

```
package rem.lift_client
package snippet
import net.liftweb._

import util._
import Helpers._
import net.liftweb.json.JsonParser._

class SearchResults {

  def render() = {
    val json_raw = "[ {\"userName\":\"John\"}, {\"userName\":\"Michael\"} ]"
    val json_parsed = parse(input)
    "li *" #> json_parsed.toString <---- NOT CORRECT
   }
 }
```

In the above example, I wanted to output a list of users as:

John

Michael

How do I interpret the **parsed** object? Any ideas are welcome, thanks.

NOTE: In addition to the accepted answer, lift-json has an excellent [documentation](https://github.com/lift/lift/tree/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json/) on this subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to extract the data with case classes.

```
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
case class User(userName: String)
json_parsed.extract[List[User]]
```

Comment: It is used to configure the extraction. For instance date formats, custom serializers etc. In this simple example default is just fine.

Comment: BTW. A recommended place to put 'formats' is a package object. Then rest of the application gets same configuration without any boilerplate.

Comment: Cool, but how did you know that "parsed" has a method called "extract"? I tried navigating the api-docs but could not find it. Is it in scala or lift docs?

Comment: What about something like: {userId: "23423", links: {self: "http://api/user/23423"}}, how can I match the "self" element?

Comment: Thanks, your answer led me to find the solution: https://github.com/lift/lift/tree/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json/